# Does extensive use of ndb models affect performance?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm new to GAE and I'm still trying to figure things out. We're developing an Android app which uses Cloud Datastore to store images, videos, text, audios, etc. So we have now over 15 types of content objects.

I've been modelling each type of object as a distinct `ndb` Model class, but I'm wondering if this kind of design could affect performance.

Specifically, wouldn't it be better to write a simple class (e.g ContentObject) which simply had a content_type, and a few generic fields as string, number and blob?

I guess I'd go for the latter if I had to worry about creating/maintaining tables (or simply knowing that there are regular db tables behind).

I really like the first option, but I had to ask, just in case.

Answer (score 4):

There are no performance differences to worry about between the 2 approaches.

With dedicated models you'll have to write a bit more code - each model needs to be handled separately. But it's simpler code, especially if eventually you will have some properties which only exist for some entities or are handled differently, which would require conditional logic with a generic model.

Building queries is also simpler with dedicated models if there are property differences, using a single model may require filling in unused properties (maybe by using default values) if they are used for sorting/filtering query results (entities with missing properties aren't indexed by the respective properties so they won't show up in the results).

On the other hand you'll need separate queries for each model, you can't obtain results for different kinds in the same query. And you'll need to maintain separate composite indexes for each kind (with a total limit of 200 such indexes per application).

If you're worrying about code duplication, which could also be a reason for which you'd consider a shared model, it's also possible to combine the common properties in a single ndb model class, with a single/common implementation for handling those common properties, and inherit that class in dedicated subclasses handling the differences. Something like this:

```
class Content(ndb.Model):
    type = ndb.StringProperty() # not really needed, cls._get_kind() can be used instead
    blob = ndb.StringProperty()
    # other generic/common content properties and related methods


class Video(Content):
    has_cc = ndb.BooleanProperty()
    # other video-specific content properties and related methods
```

But this is just an implementation approach, from the datastore perspective you're still using dedicated models - in the above example a video entity will have a `Video` kind, not a `Content` kind.

There are no tables with the datastore, the only thing shared between entities of the same kind is their `ndb` model (which is specific just for the more performant `ndb` client library, other client libraries don't have one) and the search indexes definitions.

Comment: "On the other hand you'll need separate queries for each model, you can't obtain results for different kinds in the same query". So doing a query to a base class won't work?

Comment: Nope - that base class doesn't really exist in the datastore as an entity by itself. You can do the query in the base class, but use the kind string obtained dynamically which will map to the actual kind of the inheriting class.

Comment: nice answer regarding the differences between the two approaches.